# Channel form not working for Members

Tags: members, channel, entries, url-title

When I am logged in as super admin then the channel form works (inserting the new entries to the channel) but when I am logged in as a normal user(members group user or guest user) then it does not work. I have changed lots of settings of members but this not working.

Form:
{exp:channel:form channel="wedding" return="site/ENTRY_ID" json="yes" class="form account-form" include_assets="no" include_jquery="no"}

when I am submitting the form it shows refreshes the page not saving data into the channel when set the redirect link. if json="yes" shows this message

{"success":1,"errors":[],"field_errors":[],"entry_id":null,"url_title":null,"channel_id":3}.

Comment: Please provide a little more detail here about what you mean by "not working" -- are there errors? What happens?

Comment: Actually, I create the channel form assign the channel name or all details `{exp:channel:form channel="wedding" return="site/ENTRY_ID" json="yes" class="form account-form" include_assets="no" include_jquery="no"}` but when I am submitting the form it refreshes the page not saving data into the channel.

Comment: Gotcha. For best results I recommend editing your original question right here and adding that detail, and as much other detail as you can about the issue and your current troubleshooting efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Do 'members' have permission to post entries to the channel the form is for?

Channels > [Your Channel] > Permissions
(depending on the version of ee you're using)

Comment: Hi Keith, Thanks for the reply. Yes, Members have permission to post the entries on the channel. And the channel also has set all settings. I am using the EE 5.4.0 version. Let me know if the setting is missing. Thank you